# Declare twice beginTransaction to make it work

Tags: php, doctrine

I need to declare twice this line `$connection->beginTransaction();` to make code works, otherwise if I write this line once, it throws the error **`There is no active transaction`**. Why? Is it possible to fix this?
I'm using Symfony 6.

Here is my code:

```
public function flushTable($em, $entityName, $io)
{
    $classMetaData = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor($entityName);
    $connection = $em->getConnection();
    $dbPlatform = $connection->getDatabasePlatform();
    // write this line twice otherwise it doesn't work
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    $connection->beginTransaction();

    try
    {
        $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
        $q = $dbPlatform->getTruncateTableSql($classMetaData->getTableName());
        $connection->executeUpdate($q);
        $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
        $connection->commit();

        $io->success(sprintf('Database flushed'));
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $connection->rollback();

        $io->error(sprintf($e));
    }
}
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the error? on the `try` block, or on the `catch` one?

Comment: I tried to comment all my code in the `try` only: no error. I tried to comment all my code in the `catch` only:  no error. Actually, I'm getting the error when both `try` and `catch` have code.
But when the error occurs (when I write the above line once only), it doesn't seem to pass in the `try` nor the `catch` block, because I wrote error_log at the beginning of each of them and I'm getting no error_log in my logs file.